# Can't access property in inherited class

Tags: c#

I have got a support project. There is such control hierarchy:

```
public class MyWindowControl : MyControl<WindowControl>
```

The `MyControl` has such hierarchy:

```
public abstract class MyControl<T> : MyElement<T> where T : Control, new()
```

I'm doing fixes in `WindowControl`, and stuck in a situation, that a property that i need is inside the `MyControl`, called - `Token`.

I need to get it, but there is no way that i see. Is there a way, maybe i can pass it as a parameter to the contructor? But how?

Here is an example:

```
public class MyWindowControl : MyControl<WindowControl>
{
    public MyWindowControl()
    {

    }
}

public abstract class MyControl<T> : MyElement<T> where T : Control, new()
{
    public MyControl() :
        this(new T())
    {
    }

    public MyControl(T Element) :
        base(Element)
    {
    }
}

public abstract class MyElement<T> : MyScreenElement where T : FrameworkElement, new()
{
    public MyElement() :
        this(new T())
    {
    }

    public MyElement(T Element)
    {
    }
}

public abstract class MyScreenElement
{
    public MyClass Token { get; protected set; }
}
```

So the problem is i can access token inside the MyControl, but not inside the WindowControl. How can i, in this case pass as a parameter or set as a property the Token value inside the WindowControl class object?

Please, look carefully: I'm trying to access the Token property not in the MyWindowControl, but in **WindowControl**

And again. In the current structure of the code i need to have a copy of Token in the WindowControl class. And i'm asking is there a way to do it properly or any workaround?

I don't know, maybe:

```
public class MyWindowControl : MyControl<WindowControl(this.Token)>
```

Comment: Please provide more detail and code examples if possible. Does `WindowControl` _have_ a `Token` property and you just need to get it, or do you need to add the property to the class definition?  Which constructor are you talking about?  Or are you trying to access a property of `MyControl<T>` from `WindowControl`?

Comment: Is `Token` private in `MyControl<T>`?

Comment: If the `Token` property is not `private`, you should be able to access it with no problem from `MyWindowControl`. If it's private, then think twice why you need it, or make it `protected`

Comment: `MyWindowControl` has access to everything (except private methods/properties) that `MyControl` has. Have you made it's accessors `protected` or `public`? showing more code might explain your situation better too. It's not 100% clear what you want.

Comment: i have added full code inheritance

Comment: I've just knocked up and simplified version and I can access it. What makes you think you can't?

Comment: With the code that you have given us, it looks accesible for the class `MyWindowControl`.

Comment: Because i added a method inside the WindowControl. Which makes a request to server and inside that i can't do string token = this.Token; I'm trying to access the Token property not in the MyWindowControl, but in **WindowControl**

Comment: What does the WindowControl class look like, and where is it in the inheritance chain?

Comment: @CodeCaster look at the first line of code snippets: public class MyWindowControl : MyControl<WindowControl>

Comment: I didn't ask that. `MyControl<WindowControl>` is the only place where you show `WindowControl`. If that type doesn't inherit from `MyScreenElement` nor has a member that does so, you can't access the `Token` property. Show, in your WindowControl code, how you want to access Token and from whom. You're asking _"Why can't I access `IList.Count` in the `Foo` class of `List<Foo>`?"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster again added an edit to the question, at the end

Comment: I would suggest that you've gotten yourself into a muddle. The issue isn't so much how can you access the Token in the WindowControl it's more how can you make your design less complex to achieve what you want. In short this is an [X Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: In your edited code, `Token` has a public getter, so the value is accessible in the whole inheritance chain (you can't set it, but you can get the value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified, it's like you have a class `Foo`:

```
public class Foo
{
}
```

And then create a list of that:

```
var fooList = new List<Foo>();
```

And now *in `Foo`*, you want to access `fooList.Count`. You can't. `Foo` doesn't know it's being used generically.